# tune2fs filesystem not clean

Tags: filesystems, mount

I've read in some forums that sometimes if you check tune2fs on
a mounted device, it's OK that it says filesystem state: not clean.

Can someone give me a complete explanation when this is true?

Comment: I would be careful messing around with a running filesystem. It is not clean because the underlying structures are changing, being used by the system... The question is a bit broad, if you wish better answers, detail more about what really worries you, and the exact commands used.

Comment: I'm using `tune2fs -l /dev/sda1` in a script to check the filesystem. My problem is, that if the filesystem state is "not clean" I don't exactly know if there's really something wrong or if it is just mounted. But my original question was, if someone could tell me in which cases a filesystem is shown as not clean when there's actually nothing wrong with it.